# Blogger Demo Page

Tags: blogger, demo

My Blog is : [**TechLeaps**](http://www.techleaps.in/)

I created a demo page on my blogger to to redirected other pages within my `blog.Icreate` a page like `www.techleaps.in/demo/Url adrees` I wanted to redirect/.

Now I want to create a demo page like the following = demo.techleaps. in/

Is this possible on blogger

Please explain how can I do it?

Comment: You mean that you want to a sub domain like demo.techleaps.in to become a sub page of your blogger? Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: Finally, I see. I think blogger cannot redirect the URL like `www.techleaps.in/demo/xxx`. What you can do is add a new page which contains a web address. And Blogger can only band one domain. But you can add more sub domain in your domain name provider. And you can let your sub domain like demo.techleaps.in to point to another page. For example. My Blogger is www.einverne.tk, While I make a sub domain plus.einverne.tk  to point to my google+ page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Google's Blogger platform is concerned, you cannot practice URL re-writing, ie, you cannot create any page with the URL www.techleaps.in/demo/UrlAddress.html

All the webpages on this blogging platform follow the following URL structure:
Page: www.yourdomain.in/p/contact.html
Post/Article: www.yourdomain.in/2013/11/hello-world.html

So you cannot create such a page on blogger.

Regarding the second question of creating a page with the URL demo.techleaps.in you can define a **sub-domain** in your domain-hosting account settings and do so.

Comment: sir can you explain how to create a sub-domain with the help of your domain provider

Comment: @user2445382 where is your domain hosted?

Comment: my domain is purchased from www.bigrock.com

Comment: @user2445382 follow this tutorial: http://www.bloggerworlds.com/2012/06/how-to-create-subdomain-on-bigrock-for.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for redirect one URL to another URL on your Blogger Blog. You can do it easily with the help of Custom Redirects features provided by Blogger.

Just visit blogger.com/home and go to the setting tab of your blog.
Now, click on Search preferences where you will find an oprion "Custom Redirects" under Errors and redirections heading.

NOTE: Both URLS (Source and destination) should not contain your Blog Domain Name (blog address).

Example:
Source (From) URL is http://www.example.com/year/month/something-old.html

Destination (To) URL is http://www.example.com/p/something-new.html

Now you should use these URLS:

Source (From) URL is /year/month/something-old.html

Destination (To) URL is /p/something-new.html

---

If you want to create a demo page like demo.example.com/url-address.html in blogger blog then you may create a sub-domain with the help of your domain provider.